# Above 40000 row in database, Single database vs two database which is better?

Tags: sql-server

I am designing a Student hall management software.

For this I need to used two table in database.

One table will contained 1000+ row and another table will contained 4000+ row. 1st table (1000+ row) will connect every day and It is mainly used. But the 2nd table (4000+ row) will not needed everyday. It will used for 1 time within 2 weeks.

Give me advice which option is better in below:

1. Use One database which contain 2 Table.
2. Use Two database which contain 1 Table.

Which option is fast for my software and better performance?

I am using local database. example: "AAA.mdf".

also using visual studio 2019.

Comment: 40000 rows - that's a small database, even on your cell phone.

Comment: 4000, 40000 Either way, this is too tiny to worry about

Comment: .mdf files relate to sqlserver not mysql..

Comment: I had a 80GB database that worked perfectly. You are cool with 1 DB to store your big data ;-)

Comment: Thanks  P.Salmon Sir. I Don't know about it. That's why I tag mysql. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just one database with two tables is enough this is not a lot of records to be worried about performance.

Comment: one DB should be fine, just dont forget to add indexes